# How to store data from dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, php, session-storage

I am working on a way to mark the visited links during a session.
To do so I use the **sessionStorage property** but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to store the data from a specific link, since they are generated dynamically.

So far my code looks like this :

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.caption');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            links[i].classList.add("visited");
            var thisLink = sessionStorage.setItem('link' + [i], 'true');
    });
    window.onload = function() {
    var link = sessionStorage.getItem('link' + [i]);
        if(link === 'true'){
        links[i].classList.add("visited");
        }
    }
}
```

The Php

```
    <div class="caption">
        <h1><a href="<?= $photo->url() ?>"><span><?= $photo->title()->html() ?></span></a></h1>
        <h2><a href="<?= $photo->url() ?>"><?= $photo->infos()->kt() ?></a></h2>
    </div>
```

The Css

```
.visited{
span {background-color: gold;}
}
```

Many Thanks !

Comment: I would use the URL of the link directly as the key under which you store this info, instead of going with “numbered” keys link0, link1 etc.

Comment: Btw., you are adding a new load handler for each link here - that is not a good way to go about it. Use _one_ load handler, and inside that loop over all the links.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Moving the load handler solved my issue.